# Wordpress comments security

Tags: php, wordpress

The comments section of the wordpress accepts anything that the user write without filtering the content of it for any malicious entry. I checked this by adding a javascript comment as a comment to my site. Please see the below two points regarding this issue.

1) I have setup my Wordpress site to show comments when the admin approves them. Therefore at the moment any user from the outside will not see any spam comments which I haven't been approved. However, these spam comments are appears when I login as an admin and view the site. Can I block unapproved comments on my posts when I login and view the site as an admin?

2) Are there any technical solutions for this issue? I am using "All-in-one-security&firewall" plugin and "Wordfence" plugin in my blog. It looks like these plugins are not protecting my site from commnts. Are there any free plugin that I can use to stop this thing happening again?

Comment: Try captcha for your comments form..  Visit: http://wordpress.org/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/

Comment: add captcha with your comment form and enable the option approved comments only publish.

Comment: Or, you can use another great plugin - Akismet, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet/

Comment: Captcha will stop brute force attacks (coming from robots) but anyone can add javascript or any other hacking comment by entering correct text to the captcha.

Comment: Akismet is not a free plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can always mark comments as spam in the comments section of your wordpress backend.
Also, like some suggested, it's possible to install a plugin that takes care of comments right away, so they will be put in the spam section automatically. Here are two plugins that worked fine for me and are free to use, that you could try:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/invisible-captcha/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/antispam-bee/